# Error while running a SSRS 2005 report in Internet Explorer

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

We have developed a report using SSRS 2005. This is embedded in the web application, which is built on C#/ASP.Net (3.5 framework/VS 2008).

The report is deployed in a report/db server, which is a part of two tier architecture ie. app and db. 
This report takes more than an hour for execution and producing the output, as it calls a stored procedure which processes large amount of data.
When the report is being run, and elapsed time is close to an hour, then an error message is displayed as: "Internet Explorer can not display the webpage".

Event viewer log has following message:

```
Event Type: Warning
Event Source:   ASP.NET 2.0.50727.0
Event Category: Web Event 
Event ID:   1309
Date:       1/7/2013
Time:       10:58:04 AM
User:       N/A
Computer:   --------------------
Description:
Event code: 3005 
Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred. 
Process ID: 7456 
Process name: w3wp.exe
Account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE
Exception type: AspNetSessionExpiredException 
Exception message: ASP.NET session has expired 
Request URL:http://------/ABC/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?ReportSession=1ki0jo3ouutixi555breaja4&ControlID=9ab46efcbab44cb987c5b9967fea54c3&Culture=1033&UICulture=1033&ReportStack=1&OpType=SessionKeepAlive&TimerMethod=KeepAliveMethodctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ReportViewer1TouchSession0
```

Answer (score 1):

Execution time of an hour for a report will never be viable.  What happens when the data volumes increase? What if 2 users request the report at the same time? What if 50 users request reports at the same time?

I aim for 5 seconds which is achievable even with high data volumes and complex requirements.

You should revisit your SP code and/or indexing.

Answer (score 0):

What Mike said. If however you like a reaaally slow report, you can set your session timeout in Web.Config:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9(vs.80).aspx